# sources.list broken -- missing universe, multiverse etc.. in 18.04.1 server?

Tags: software-sources

So I just fresh installed 18.04.1 server from this ISO: ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso

This is how my /etc/apt/sources.list looks:

```
svy@emerg-reg-srv:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
svy@emerg-reg-srv:~$
```

It's missing universe and multiverse, all src ones. I can't even install mc.
So what's going on here? Did something break during installation?

Comment: You must `sudo add-apt-repository {universe,restricted,multiverse}` if you want them.

Comment: With Server edition in 18.04, universe/multiverse/backports are not enabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to know what happened but here is what the file looks like from a vanilla desktop install.  I removed the comments.

You can remove the "us." if you don't want to use the US server.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: You can condense all that into four lines https://pastebin.com/5agGcMkb or eight if you're including source.

Comment: @hiigaran Yes, mine is three lines long because I don't use backports. But the point of my answer was to show what the stock version is.

Answer (score 2):

I installed 18.04.1 server a few times and saw the same result. No, it doesn't look like something went wrong with your install, but that someone upstream made the change.

There are also changes with default group membership. lpadmin was missing.

These are changes between 18.04 and 18.04.1

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the multiverse repo by running:

sudo apt-add-repository multiverse && sudo apt-get update